# Quit Application when all forms is closed

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I want to have a lot of forms in my Gtk# application. I want to quit application when user close all form. I try to use next code:

```
    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    /*Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;*/


    if(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count==0)
    {
        Gtk.Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

But System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count allways return "0" regardless of the number of open forms (OS Ubuntu 12.04). How can I solve this problem and get actual quantity of open forms?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a guess, as never having written a GTK app, but if you're opening GTK windows, shouldn't you be querying GTK for the window count, not System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but do you close the main form?

Comment: Will, thanks alot for your response. Maybe you're right, but then I get a list of open Gtk.Window? Matthias Koch, yes I close main and secondary window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also tried to find an answer to that issue.
My current implementation is based on some concept I have seen in MS Visual Studio documentation:
in the project's main class maintain a static list of open windows.
do not use the delete event but the destroy event of the GTK# window (with the OnDelete event handler something did not work, if I remember correctly the windows delete cannot be directly called by a member function).
In the OnDestoy event handler: when the window gets destroyed then remove it from the static list. Then check the list for being empty, then quit the application.
Not sure if this is really ideal for GTK# windows but in my application this concept works.
regards
Harald